# Android: how to create a button with a centre line in it?

Tags: android, button

i want to create  a button with green color background and a white line in center, like in the image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRgrd.jpg]

Comment: you can use background image

Comment: You could simply use a 9 patch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a 9 patch (name it btn_green.9.png - mind the extension!), put it in your `/res/drawable-mdpi` folder.
You can use this one:

[image]

This is how it is shown in the draw9patch tool:

[image]

This is how to add it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It only uses 1 View, so it's a superfast (the less Views, the better performances)!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ImageButton with Background attribute, and then create a View for the line setting the margin attribute to move it the position you want.

This is a very fast xml, but you can start playing with it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#009900" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is assuming, you don't want to use that image as the imageButton.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the button like that, you can use FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#009900" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" /> 
</FrameLayout>
```

The reason why i'm using FrameLayout is to overlap Views. so try this code, i hope it works.